# How can I avoid having to use decltype when calling this template?

Tags: c++, templates, exception, variant, decltype

I have the following code, which I use to automatically catch `bad_variant_access` errors. I am aware that I can use `get_if` to simplify error handling, but in this particular case, I do not want a pointer. This code seems to work, but is redundant. As you can see I always have to do `assert_no_bad_variant_access<decltype(v), int>(v, "msg");`. Could I somehow simplify this to avoid having to pass the `decltype(v)`? Seems wordy to me.

Ideally, I would like to have a template to which I only have to pass `get_T`. `variant_T` should somehow be determined automatically.

[Play with the code.](https://godbolt.org/z/KGWEhe)

```
template <typename variant_T, typename get_T>
get_T assert_no_bad_variant_access(variant_T& v, std::string_view msg) {
  try {
    return std::get<get_T>(v);
  } catch (const std::bad_variant_access& bva) {
    std::cout << msg << '\n';
    get_T t;
    return t;
  }
}

int main() 
{

    std::variant<int, double, std::string> v = "hi there!";
    auto result1 = assert_no_bad_variant_access<decltype(v), std::string>(v, "std::string failed");
    auto result2 = assert_no_bad_variant_access<decltype(v), int>(v, "int failed");
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend not naming this `assert`. One would not expect a failed assertion to be perfectly fine. Something like `<name>_or_default` is more telling of what the function actually does, though the logging complicates that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reorder the template parameters. Let `variant_T` be second, and so it may get deduced

```
template <typename get_T, typename variant_T>
get_T assert_no_bad_variant_access(variant_T& v, std::string_view msg) {
  try {
    return std::get<get_T>(v);
  } catch (const std::bad_variant_access& bva) {
    std::cout << msg << '\n';
    get_T t;
    return t;
  }
}

int main() 
{

    std::variant<int, double, std::string> v = "hi there!";
    auto result1 = assert_no_bad_variant_access<std::string>(v, "std::string failed");
    auto result2 = assert_no_bad_variant_access<int>(v, "int failed");
    return 0;   
}
```

Remember, we can get away with specifying part of the template's arguments only if the *trailing* ones can be deduced.

As an aside, you don't need to use exceptions to detect this condition. The `std::variant` API includes [`std::holds_alternative`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative). You can check it directly. This will avoid using exceptions for regular flow of control.

Comment: Amazing answer! Really love this! Could you tell me more about the partial templates? I was not aware about that at all! Do you have a recommendation what I could read about this topic?

Comment: @User12547645 - cppreference has a decent rundown of this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction